# apache point wildcard subdomain to directory?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

With apache, i want a wildcard so my domains can go to the appropriate folder. www should be ignore/go into root. How do i setup the rules?

```
         'domain.com' to go to '/var/www/prj/www/root'
'ANYTHING.domain.com' to go to '/var/www/prj/www/ANYTHING'
```

Currently my file is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/www
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/prj/www/root
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wildcard.domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/prj/www/%1
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: That did the trick. and no modrewrite to boot!